# How to return the value of the nth cell to the right of a matched value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table

```
Video UID   Tag 1       Start Timecode [ms] End Timecode [ms]   Tag 2           Start Timecode [ms]     End Timecode [ms]   ...     Tag N-1     Start Timecode [ms]     End Timecode [ms]
7b9c69      Shopping    0                   16178               Bank            0                       16178                       x           x                       x
2f20f1      Home        0                   9720                Parked          0                       74785                       x           x                       x
104473      Smoking     0                   357146              Journey Start   4349                    36831                       x           x                       x
```

I want to search each row and find the `Smoking` tag and return the corresponding `Start Timecode [ms]` value. I then want to do the same but return the corresponding `End Timecode [ms]` value instead.

The end result would look as follows

```
Smoking
Video UID    Start timecode    End timecode
104473       0                 357146
```

Searching for the `Smoking` tag is not a problem, I can use index/match. The problem I have is returning the 1st cell value (`start timecode`) or 2nd cell value (`end time code`) or nth cell value to the right of the returned matched value (`Smoking`).

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Vlookup only works if Smoking is under 1 column e.g. column B. If Smoking is in Column B for row 2 and column F for row 3 it doesnt work as col_index_num won't be dynamically updated. Unless theres a way to update this?

Comment: This is precisely what the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is designed to do.  Just adjust the col_index_num to be the column value to the right you want to return (2 for the Start timecode and 3 for the End timecode)

Comment: a vlookup only works if all the smoking tags are in column B. If you have a smoking tag in column C it wont work because the col_index_num has to be changed accordingly. Is there a way to make col_index_num dynamic so that it returns the cell that has matched Smoking?

Comment: Alright, with a datasetup like that, finding the tag becomes difficult since it can be in any number of columns.  How do you find the tag currently?  Is it just separate matches on all of your different tag columns?

Comment: i use index/match `=INDEX(B2:BX2,MATCH("Smoking",B2:BX2,0),0)` but doesnt work because i dont have a column_num for the index function (so the last 0 isnt correct)

Comment: Wait, so you're doing this for only a single row?  Just do a +1 to your match fo rthe starttime and a +2 to your match for the endtime

Comment: Yes, doing it row by row, I added +1 to the returned match value but i still have a problem with column_num for the index function as I don't know what column to input - this depends on what column the smoking tag is --> =INDEX(C2:CX2,MATCH("Smoking Real Cigarette",C2:CX2,0)+1,`0`)

Comment: You're already returning the column, leave off the last 0: `=INDEX(C2:CX2,MATCH("Smoking Real Cigarette",C2:CX2,0)+1)` or if you want to explicitly show that it's the column you're returning, move the match to the column argument: `=INDEX(C2:CX2,1,MATCH("Smoking Real Cigarette",C2:CX2,0)+1)`

Comment: works like a charm thanks! follow up question, what if I have more than 1 smoking tag in the same row? is there a way to find the nth match?

Comment: yes, but then the formula becomes an array formula.  Probably best to open a new question since that is fundamentally different from this question.